# PLL on ATSAM4S2A doesn't go higher than 60MHz

Tags: c

I have a problem with an ATSAM4S2A device. I try to configure the PLLB to run with an external clock (in my case 16MHz) with almost 120MHz. If I take a value too high in the MULB / DIVB Register then no more clock is provided.

Here my initialisation code:

```
REG_CKGR_MOR |= CKGR_MOR_KEY_PASSWD | CKGR_MOR_MOSCXTEN;

//wait for crystal to become ready
while (!(REG_PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MOSCXTS));

//select crystal for main clock
REG_CKGR_MOR |= CKGR_MOR_KEY_PASSWD | CKGR_MOR_MOSCSEL;
REG_PMC_MCKR |= PMC_MCKR_CSS_MAIN_CLK;

while (!(REG_PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MCKRDY));

REG_PMC_MCKR |= PMC_MCKR_PRES_CLK_1;

while (!(REG_PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MCKRDY));

//Write PLL Value (16MHz * (14+1) / 2 = 16MHz * 7.5 = 120MHz)
REG_CKGR_PLLBR |= CKGR_PLLBR_MULB(14);
REG_CKGR_PLLBR |= CKGR_PLLBR_DIVB(2);
    
REG_PMC_MCKR |= PMC_MCKR_CSS_PLLB_CLK;
```

With the value MULB = 12 and DIVB = 4 (52MHz) everything works fine.

Has anybody an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you get 60 for MULB = 14 and DIVB = 4?  If not, then maybe the multiplier is too high.

Comment: No this doesn't work either. the maximum Frequency for the PLL is stated as 240MHz. 16MHz * (14+1) = 240 MHz so this should be correct. 

Also: Datasheet states that division is first applied then multiplication so in fact is: 16MHz / 2 = 8MHz * (14+1) = 120MHz